# Does it make sense to have two classes related by a 1:1 cardinality?

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I am currently coursing Computer Engineering and I remember a professor of a class called Introduction to Informational Systems saying that two classes related by a 1:1 cardinality does not make sense.

For example: I have the `Client` class and the `Telephone` class. Let's supose that the client can only have one phone. The professor said that does not make sense creating the `Telephone class`, and telephone should be an attribute of the `Client` class. I absolutely agree with him.

But now I'm taking the Software Engineering class and the professor (not the same) did not make any comments about this issue, and now I'm really confused about this.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your Introduction to Information Systems professor was correct. And your SE professor, too (assuming his lack of comments makes him a contrarian). They are each right depending on your requirements and the domain you're working with. But without any other details, it's hard to model this for you, and I would lean towards what your CE professor had said. Keep in mind all those fun little principles you learned: KISS, DRY, etc., and apply them to your problem.

If `Client` will never ever possibly have more than one telephone number and no other entity in your domain needs a telephone number, then a separate `Telephone` class isn't necessary. In the real world, if your requirements are vague, find out more information from your client.

If somebody down the road decides `Client`s can take on more than one telephone number, or another entity is introduced into your domain that needs a telephone number, this is a fairly easy refactoring to accomplish.

So with that in mind, let's say your `Client` had a separate `Address` class that included the telephone number instead. Maybe that `Address` class gets re-used by another class, maybe `Invoice` or `Shipment`, where an `Address` could be shared or applied in both cases. In this example, you might want `Address` (`Telephone`) to be its own class.

In your example, `Telephone` might be a little too contrived. You'd want it to be a separate class for re-use if it had many properties (`AreaCode`, `InternationalPrefix`, `Number`, etc.), but if `Client` just needed a string-value called `Telephone` that a user would be typing in merely for reference, then it probably doesn't make sense to be its own class.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to re-use the `Telephone` class, it won't be very useful having it as a part of the `Client` class. That would be one really good reason. If you leave it in the `Client` class, it implies that it is intrinsically part of the `Client` even when you use it elsewhere, which I doubt you would ever mean.

Sometimes though, it makes sense to model 2 entities with a 1:1 relationship as separate classes. Perhaps you have a `Client` and you also have `ClientBilling`. You do not want all of your programmers to have access to the `ClientBilling` so you move it into its own class where it can be separately controlled.

Perhaps your structure is huge, and shipping the whole thing around isn't normally necessary. By breaking it into functional pieces, you can reduce the size of the data to only that needed for a particular function.

Perhaps the 1:1ness isn't necessarily intrinsic to the data and a reasonable guess would be that it will not always be that way. Tour `Telephone` example falls into this category I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say 1:1 relationships (mandatory on both ends) are suspicious and should be carefully considered to be sure they are needed. Usually it's a trade-off between flexibility and simplicity of the diagram (flexibility because it will be easier to change the diagram in the future and adapt it to new requirements if you keep the two classes against simplicity of having to maintain one class instead of two)